# Turn a field of comma-separated zip codes into a list of cities

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql

I have two tables:

1. people, with columns user_id (unique) and zipcodes (comma-separated value; multiple zipcodes possible in a single value);
2. location, with columns zipcode, city, and state (each zip is associated with a city and state, and the table includes the entire US).

I'm trying to create a table that ranks cities by user_id density.

So, first, I want to get a table displaying user_id alongside the cities with which each user_id is associated in the "people" table. A user_id can be associated with multiple cities.

Then, I'm planning on just counting the unique user_ids for each city and ranking the cities from most to least dense in terms of user_id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Turning comma-separated column values into separate rows

Turn your comma-separated column into separate rows with `unnest()` firstly building the array out of the string with `string_to_array()`:

```
select 
  user_id, 
  unnest(string_to_array(zipcodes, ',')) AS zipcode
from people
```

Generating test data:

```
create table people(user_id int, zipcodes text);
insert into people values (1, '22333,12354,45398,12398');
into people values (2, '54389,45398,12398');
insert into people values (3, '34534,12398,94385');
```

Outcome:

```
 user_id | zipcode
---------+---------
       1 | 22333
       1 | 12354
       1 | 45398
       1 | 12398
       2 | 54389
       2 | 45398
       2 | 12398
       3 | 34534
       3 | 12398
       3 | 94385
```

### Ranking cities by users density

Combine the information about cities with extracted information about associated zipcodes with users using `LEFT JOIN`. `COUNT()` your users and use window function `DENSE_RANK()` to assign ranking position. Ties are equally positioned in this case.

Query:

```
SELECT
    l.city
  , COUNT(DISTINCT p.user_id) AS distinct_users -- is distinct really needed?
  , DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(DISTINCT p.user_id) DESC) AS city_ranking
FROM location l
LEFT JOIN (
  select 
    user_id, 
    unnest(string_to_array(zipcodes, ',')) AS zipcode
  from people
  ) p USING ( zipcode )
GROUP BY l.city
ORDER BY city_ranking
```

Generating test data:

```
create table location(zipcode text, city text);
insert into location values 
  ('22333', 'City1'), 
  ('12354', 'City2'), 
  ('45398', 'City3'), 
  ('12398', 'City4'), 
  ('54389', 'City5'), 
  ('34534', 'City6'), 
  ('94385', 'City7');
```

Outcome:

```
 city  | distinct_users | city_ranking
-------+----------------+--------------
 City4 |              3 |            1
 City3 |              2 |            2
 City2 |              1 |            3
 City1 |              1 |            3
 City5 |              1 |            3
 City6 |              1 |            3
 City7 |              1 |            3
```

---

### Additional notes

Consider if you really need to count distinct users for zipcodes. Is it possible that user has the same zipcode more than once?

If that is the case, you may use `DISTINCT` in the first query, so that you don't need to do it within the ranking query like that:

```
select distinct
  user_id,
  unnest(string_to_array(zipcodes, ',')) AS zipcode
from people;
```

Remove the distinct part in ranking query and you're good to go.